# I need to click a button on quora but dont know how

Tags: python, button, buttonclick, quora

I am trying to make this thing where a bot can answer questions on quora. But while creating this I ran into a problem with clicking on the answer button. It just wouldn't work. Anyone some kind of advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium` to click a button in python.

**Example:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://codepad.org')

python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='lang' and @value='Python']")[0]
python_button.click()
```

Hope it was usefull

*Edit:*

*You can get the XPath of an element by copying it from the console (when inspecting the element)*

[image: try it]

Comment: yeah i found this but didn't know what to put in where.